# Vue.js v-show won't change from other component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component

I have this component in vue.js

[image: Component 1]

When I press one of the points, it changes my "selected" to a value.

Then I have 4 hidden components imported into this component. These have v-show="selected == value".  When I press e.g "oplysninger" it now shows this info.vue component. It works as it should.

[image: component 2]

Then I coded an emitter with eventbus that communicates with the settings.vue (where "oplysninger" is shown). When i press the little arrow in the left corner, it changes my "selected" on settings.vue and then closes this tab.

BUT it doesn't do anything. I have tried to console.log to see if the emitter event goes back and changes my value on settings, and it does change it.

[image: logs]

```
test -> from info.vue
test2 -> from settings.vue
0 -> is the value of selected on settings.vue.
```

Can anyone tell me why i doesn't close my info.vue tab and then shows the navigation again?

CODE:

SETTINGS.VUE

```
this.$eventHub.$on('changeSelect', function () {
      console.log('test2')
      this.selected = 0
      console.log(this.selected)
    })
```

INFO.VUE

```
<div v-show="active == 0" class="header">
      <img class="backArrow"  @click.prevent="select()"  src="static/img/icons/backArrowSettings.svg" alt="">
      <h3 class="headline"> Oplysninger </h3>
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="">Gem</a>
    </div>

select () {
      console.log('test')
      this.$eventHub.$emit('changeSelect', 0)
    },
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Settings.vue have a condition to show navigation with selected === 0 ?

Comment: @proJS yes it has :)